# Apache superset theming and styling

Tags: python, apache-superset

Hi All is there any tutorial to change the template? I tried to create my own variables.less and assigned it on the basic.html but no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to rebuild the assets:

`cd` into the /assets directory; then

  `$ npm install
  $ npm install webpack
  $ npm run prod`

If this doesn't work try, https://superset.incubator.apache.org/installation.html#making-your-own-build